# Hook when editing user

Tags: hooks, users, actions

I am trying to run a function. And that function I would like it to run when I open a user's form (**in my wp-admin**).

Which Hook would be the one I should use ??
Ideally, you should run the function once the user form fields are displayed.

¿¿ after_showing_user ??

---

I am currently using:

```
Add_action ('profile_update', 'refreshSize', 10, 2);
```

To do so, click the "Update User" button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is CORRECT

```
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'limpiamosVariables');

function limpiamosVariables($user){

        // My Code Sample
        update_option( "var_ios_token", get_field('token_user', 'user_'.$user->id) );


};
```